# Showing Customer Details Instead of customer_id

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to getting the customer details in wishlist instead of showing the customer_id, I do in following way

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory
 */
protected $_wishlistFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory){
    $this->_wishlistFactory = $wishlistFactory;
}

public function getWishlistByCustomerId($customerId)
{
    $wishlistCollections = $this->_wishlistFactory->create()->getCollection();
    return $wishlistCollections->getData();
}
```

form this I got whole list wishlists with customer_id

```
[
{
    "wishlist_id": "2",
    "customer_id": "8",
    "shared": "0",
    "sharing_code": "138258069f07f9e03395ac6c71a02eff",
    "updated_at": "2014-01-03 12:41:46"
},
{
    "wishlist_id": "3",
    "customer_id": "2",
    "shared": "0",
    "sharing_code": "0b29c50279346cba61010443e0410cb8",
    "updated_at": "2013-12-06 10:48:04"
}
]
```

but my acceptation is how to show it in like

```
[
{
    "wishlist_id": "2",
    "customer_id": {
                        //TODO Customer Details
                    },
    "shared": "0",
    "sharing_code": "138258069f07f9e03395ac6c71a02eff",
    "updated_at": "2014-01-03 12:41:46"
}
]
```

Is it possible to show this, I have try buy looping the wishlist and send the customer_id to `\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface` but it take more time. Is there any shortest and coolest way to show the stuffs of foriegn keys.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want do that on frontend, when Customer is logged in, get it from session:

```
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

public function getCurrentCustomer(){
 if($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()):
        echo $customerGroup=$this->_customerSession->getCustomer();
    endif;
}
```

Otherwise You have to load Customer.

Where do you want use this function?
It may be important to solve it better